# Script Component not Being detected by Vuforia's Default Trackable Event Handler Script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a Script Component named 'Start' inside a GameObject named 'StartSpawn' and I am trying to run a function from Start when the target is found but Unity/Visual Studio is not detecting the Start script component. I even tried restarting both Unity and Visual Studio to only worsen the problem. When I opened both programs again and inspecting the code, the code I added was deleted and the script DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs was back to its original code. Btw, the function I'm calling to Instantiates a Prefab.

Here's the code inside the DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs:

```
protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
{
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        var rendererComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);
        //test
        Start summoner = GetComponentInChildren<Start>();

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        //test spawn
        summoner.OnAppear();
    }
}
```

Please give help as soon as possible, much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts with the name `Start` are not supported by the Unity Editor.
Just rename your script to something else, e.g. `Summoner`.

When renaming, make sure the class name matches the file name.

Comment: Just tried that. I changed it from Start to StartAll but it was no good.

Comment: `StartAll` works. Did your class and the file have the same name? Perhaps you have to Refresh the assets. In Unity's menu select `Assets`->`Refresh`.

Comment: StartAll should turn green inside Visual Studio if it's being detected, right? Although, it doesn't change at all. It even returns an error in the console:

`Library\PackageCache\com.ptc.vuforia.engine@8.3.9\Vuforia\Scripts\DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs(95,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StartAll' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Can you try to add it as `Component` to a `GameObject`?
Are you able to create a new script from within the Unity Editor and will that script be detected by Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, to both questions. The script that I'm using is to run a function from `StartAll` is the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs`, the one from the Vuforia package. Maybe the reason is that they aren't in the same folder? The `Defualt...` script is inside the `Packages` folder while the 'StartAll' is inside the `Assets` folder

Comment: The Vuforia package does not know your script, that is indeed the problem. You can try to add your own namespace to the class with [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) or you can use delegates and listen to events (which would be a more OOP-way of working with frameworks).

Comment: Any tips on how to add namespaces? And what if I duplicate the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs' (of course changing the name of the script) and put it in the `Assets` folder, can I use it to replace the original `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs'?

Comment: add `namespace MyNamespace {` around your class. then add the namespace to the class (`DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs`) by writing `using MyNamespace;` on top of it. You can't replace classes like that.

Comment: @FrancisAaronMilano yes. something looks messed up though

Comment: Any ideas what that might be? If I tried `using AugReal` AugReal should pop out in the list of possible names right? But it doesn't show.

Comment: Sorry, no clue. Could be a lot of things.

Comment: My problem now is that, `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` can't use `AugReal` but other scripts that are inside `Assets` folder can.

Comment: Any solution to this?? I am also stuck at the same problem.